# Change td content html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, tr

I have this HTML code, and I want to change the table td content (with new content instead of Old content) using Javascript.
How can I do it?

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label class='A' >A:</label> </td>
    <td class='myClass'/>Old Content</td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What have you already, and can you give an example of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.myClass')

// If your content contains only text:
element.textContent = 'New Content'

// If your content contains more complicated tags:
element.innerHTML = '<strong>New Content</strong>'
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="A">A:</label></td>
    <td class="myClass">Old Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```